# Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\wamp\www\testing\kd_xmlrpc.php

Tags: php

I am getting an error like

> Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in
>   C:\wamp\www\testing\kd_xmlrpc.php on line 83

I have also tried to replace the `&$this` to `$this` by removing the `&` but at that time the xmlrpc file was not working.

So please guide me where I am wrong in these? Or do I need to update my xmlrpc.php file? If yes let me know from where I can get the latest one..

Once I move the same files to the production environment I am getting the fatal error instead of deprecated we can hide the deprecated but not fatal error..

Why I am getting the fatal error when I moved the files to the production server?

Comment: Most likely because there are differences in configuration between your testing and production environments.

Comment: How about you show us the relevant parts of `kd_xmlrpc.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Call-time pass-by-reference is something you may find in older code. It's easy to remove the error once you know how to look for them.

In PHP 5.4+, passing variables by reference is possible, but only in one way. There used to be another way in earlier versions which isn't allowed anymore.

```
// causes errors!
function myFunc($arg) { }
myFunc(&$arg);

// legal
function myFunc(&$arg) { }
myFunc($var);
```

Fix these problems by changing the problematic function calls (and the called function itself) to the allowed method of pass-by-reference.